# change the name of existing param limit in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to chanage the name of `limit` param in `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` so that i can integrate the sencha touch app with my existing `PHP` pages. so is there a way to change the name of the existing parameters supported by `sencha touch` framework.c

here is the code of my `proxy` within the `store`

```
proxy:{

            type:'ajax',
            url:'getData.php',
            actionMethods:{

                read: 'POST',

            },
            reader:{

                type:'json',
                totalProperty:'count',
                rootProperty:'rows'
            },
            extraParams:{

                _search:'false',
                t:'G'

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `limitParam` on your proxy.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-limitParam